# How to inject Doctrine Entity Manager into Symfony 4 Service

Tags: symfony, doctrine, symfony4

I have a controller

```
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface:
class ExampleController{
   public function someFunction(ExampleService $injectedService){
       $injectedService->serviceFunction();
    }
}
```

With a Service

```
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;
class ExampleService{
    public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $em){
        ...
    }    
}
```

However, calls to `someFunction()` fail due to 0 parameters being passed (the EntityManagerInterface is not being injected).  I am attempting to use the EntityManager from the Service.  Autowiring is on.  I've tried the solutions for Symfony3 but they don't seem to work unless I'm missing something.

Edit: Here is my services.yaml:

```
services:
    _defaults:
        autowire: true
        autoconfigure: true
        public: false 

    App\:
        resource: '../src/*'
        exclude: '../src/{Entity,Migrations,Tests,Kernel.php}'

    App\Controller\:
        resource: '../src/Controller'
        tags: ['controller.service_arguments']
```

Comment: Your code should work with the autowiring, can we see your services.yaml

Comment: @Smaïne Yes, added now.  Some Symfony 2/3 solutions have a `services: your.service.here: class: app\service\here arguments: [@doctrine.orm.entity_manager]` but I'm not 100% that I've put the correct service and service class, or if that even applies for my scenario.

Comment: can you give me the error, I have same configuration and it's working for me

Comment: if you call `someFunction()` yourself you are responsable to give the injected service.. nothing DI can do for you.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution? I have the exact same issue.

Answer (score 15):

Use only in Symfony 4.

```
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;
use App\Entity\Name; //if you use entity for example Name

class ExampleService{
    private $em;
    public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $em)
    {
        $this->em = $em;
    }

    function newName($code) // for example with a entity
    {
        $name = new Name();
        $name->setCode($code); // use setter for entity

        $this->em->persist($name);
        $this->em->flush();
    }
}
```

Comment: But error throw: `MyService::__construct() must implement interface Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface, string given`

Answer (score 5):

I know it's an old post, but just in case somebody struggles with this, there's a typo in the use statment:

```
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface: //<- see that's a colon, not a semicolon
```

Answer (score 2):

Agree with Yarimadam. Service container, dependency injection and autowiring is not a story about injecting into methods. Dependencies injected into objects we are calling "services".

When application is up, service container is built injecting one services into another ones via class constructor or "set" method invocation.

Your `ExampleController::someFunction` is intended to be called only by you, so only way how this method will receive `$injectedService` as an argument, is that you will pass it evidently. This is the wrong way.

Answer (score 1):

A classic symfony service with autowiring uses constructor injection method to inject dependencies. In your case, you don't have a constructor.

You may consider to add a constructor method and set dependency to a private class property. And use accordingly.

Or you can utilize [setter injection](https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/injection_types.html#setter-injection).

Service Configuration:

```
services:
 app.example_controller:
     class: Your\Namespace\ExampleController
     calls:
         - [setExampleService, ['@exampleService']]
```

Controller Class:

```
class ExampleController
{
    private $exampleService;

    public function someFunction() {
        $this->exampleService->serviceFunction();
    }

    public function setExampleService(ExampleService $exampleService) {
        $this->exampleService = $exampleService;
    }
}
```

Comment: ExampleService class contains a constructor.  Although missing from the snippet, the service has a `em` property and the constructor has `$this->em = $em`.  The documentation states "You can specify [the argument in YAML]".  The wording made me think this was optional.  Is it in fact required?

Comment: How do you execute the class method ExampleController->someFunction ? Could you provide the contex? If you execute this method manually you have to pass the dependency. Thats the expected behaviour.