# easy admin 3 filter AssociationField

Tags: php, symfony, easyadmin

I'm struggling to find a solution to filtering the Assocation field list in edit view.

Situation:

- `User` has `allowedSuppliers` ManyToMany to `Supplier`
- `Website` has `enabledSuppliers` ManyToMany to `Supplier`

Based on the user roles I want to only show a selection of `Supplier` that is in the `User`'s `allowedSuppliers`

Is it possible to filter these so the user can't see non-allowed options`enabledSuppliers` Association Field?

Answer (score 2):

This can be done by changing the choices via setFormTypeOptions on the Field in configureFields.
I've put an example below that checks if user roles is not `ROLE_ADMIN` if not it will only show the allowed choices, this seems to work just the way I want it to.

Took a bit of guesswork and digging since this wasn't clearly explained in the docs.

```
public function configureFields(string $pageName): iterable
{
    $fields = [];
    if (array_search('ROLE_ADMIN', $this->getUser()->getRoles()) === false) {
        /** @var User|null $user */
        $user = $this->entityManager->getRepository(User::class)->findOneBy([
            'username' => $this->getUser()->getUsername()
        ]);
        if ($user) {
            $fields[] = AssociationField::new('suppliers')->onlyOnForms()->setFormTypeOptions([
                "choices" => $user->getEnabledSuppliers()->toArray()
            ]);
        }
    } else {
        $fields[] = AssociationField::new('suppliers')->onlyOnForms();
    }
    return $fields;
}
```

Comment: can you tell me how you have implemented the `enitityManager`-Property? I tried this with injection via the constructor, but the constructor in not called on my CrudContoller.

Comment: You want to use the [entityManagerInterface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49618780/how-to-inject-doctrine-entity-manager-into-symfony-4-service)